# Mac Excel annoying jump to other desktop when closing window

Tags: mac, ms-office

As the sloppy title tries to state; I have multiple windows of Excel open on different Desktops. When I am working on one desktop and I close an Excel window/book, Mac jumps to another desktop where it can find an open Excel workbook.

This is super annoying and disruptive for workflow.

I tested and this does not happen with Numbers which means this is a Microsoft Excel issue.

Is there anyway / hack to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Try System Prefs >Mission Control > 'When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application. Uncheck. [This will probably be a slightly different path in Ventura. Can't test].

Comment: Thanks but this is already unchecked on my Mac (using Ventura fwiw).